# Delete a record if it is not confirmed, else mark it for deletion: django

Tags: django

I have a simple model:

```
class VIP(models.Model):
   member=models.ForeignUser(User,related_name='user_task')
   confirmed=models.CharField(max_length=3,default='No')
   requested_deletion=models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
```

What I want is if the user wants to be deleted from the table, he should be deleted completely if confirmed=No. Else for reqeusted_deletion to be set today.

May be I am overthinking this but I feel my approach is a resource waster since I am hitting the database twice. It might be the only way but i wanna know of possibilities. In my views.py:

```
   status=Task.objects.values('confirmed').get(member=request.user)
   if status['confirmed']=='No':
       #delete fully
       s=Task.objects.get(member=request.user)
       s.delete()
```

Is there another way or it is that one only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why double check bro??

use this

```
status=Task.objects.get(member=request.user)
   if status.confirmed=='No':
       status.delete()
```